# The policies in Laravel are not working for me, this is my code

Tags: laravel, policy

I can't get the policies to work in my Laravel project, I installed a new project to test from scratch, I have this controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\User;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->authorize('viewAny', auth()->user());
        return response("Hello world");
    }
}
```

This policy:

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response;
use App\Models\User;

class UserPolicy
{    
    public function viewAny(User $user): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and this my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
}
```

And I get error 403: THIS ACTION IS UNAUTHORIZED. I hope someone can help me with my problem. Thank you

I have also tried to modify the AuthServiceProvider file, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Looks good. Have you cleared caches: `artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: @miken32 I already deleted it but nothing changes, it still gives the same error

Comment: This sounds like a actions that don't require models, since it is only the authenticated user that matters and you are only passing it in the hope this Policy would be used: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#controller-actions-that-dont-require-models

Comment: @lagbox I tried this way and it doesn't work either '$this->authorize('viewAny', User::class);'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to verify that the user has permission to access the page. Make sure that whoever is trying to access the page is a user, so that the policy can authorize it or not.

To test without a starter kit, create a user and log in with it.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class UserController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        // create a new user
        $user = \App\Models\User::factory()->create();

        // login with the created user
        Auth::login($user);
        $this->authorize('viewAny', \App\Models\User::class);
        return response("Hello world");
    }
}
```

However, if you wish to grant access to guest users, you can utilize the `?` symbol to make the `User` model optional:

```
public function viewAny(?User $user)
{
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I had forgotten the model, I added it there. I made the changes you suggested but it still gives me a 403 error

Comment: @Patricio Check my edited awnser, maybe `?User` is what you are looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Have to add your policy in App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider?

```
protected $policies = [
    User::class => UserPolicy::class
];
```

Comment: If right. I have added User::class => UserPolicy::class in my AuthServiceProvider

Comment: Policies are auto registered for a long time now. Haven’t needed to manually register since like Laravel 5